# Can lmfit output the correlation matrix as an array?

Tags: lmfit

Can lmfit output a complete correlation matrix as a numpy array?

I know `result.covar` will output the covariance matrix as an array, and correlation coefficients between all the parameters can be shown with `result.fit_report(show_correl=True, min_correl=0)`.

But I cannot find a way to get an easily formatted array of the correlation matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `result.covar` is a numpy array, you could format that as you like.

If you have a recent version of `lmfit`, you can try:

```
result.fit_report(correl_mode='table')
```

to print out a correlation table.  Several of the documented examples use this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd seen that fit_report argument before but your comment about _recent version_ made me check and I realised my lmfit had not actually updated when I ran 'conda update lmfit'. I've now updated and it works. Thanks.